# Stringify member name similar to #define str(s) #s in C

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

Is there any way to stringify a member name in C# for .NET 4.0 like you would in C by using the `#define str(s) #s` macro?

```
public Double MyDouble
{
    get { return _MyDouble;}
    set 
    { 
        _MyDouble = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyDouble");
        // The below item would refactor correctly if C# had a stringify pre-processor
        // RaisePropertyChanged(str(MyDouble));
    }
}
private Double _MyDouble;
```

Re-factorization breaks the raise property changed event if I have `Search in Strings` disabled or breaks completely unrelated strings if it is enabled. Sometimes I won't notice until a UI element no longer responds to changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, unfortunately. Currently you would have to use something like PostSharp or [NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver) to do this reliably.

Note that in C# 5 you'll be able to do this:

```
public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string member = "")
{
}
```

And you would use it like so:

```
public Double MyDouble
{
    get { return _MyDouble;}
    set 
    { 
        _MyDouble = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And the C# 5 compiler will automatically fill in the the optional parameter.

Comment: Is there an alternative in C# 4.0 such as using reflection to get a member name?

Comment: @NtscCobalt I would go with NotifyPropertyWeaver. You might be able to get away with something using Reflection, but remember that the JIT can inline things, so the results aren't guaranteed. Plus properties are just fancy accessors for methods, again making walking the stack ugly.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific case of `OnPropertyChanged` the best you could do is the following (though not ideal obviously)...

```
this.OnPropertyChanged(x => x.Member);
```

...and...

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
{
    var propertyName = GetPropertyName(property.Body);
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null) this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
private static string GetPropertyName(Expression expression)
{
    switch (expression.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;
            var supername = GetPropertyName(memberExpression.Expression);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(supername))
                return memberExpression.Member.Name;

            return String.Concat(supername, '.', memberExpression.Member.Name);

        case ExpressionType.Call:
            var callExpression = (MethodCallExpression)expression;
            return callExpression.Method.Name;

        case ExpressionType.Convert:
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression;
            return GetPropertyName(unaryExpression.Operand);

        case ExpressionType.Parameter:
            return String.Empty;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

...along these lines....

Comment: This chunk of code needs a little more context. Where does `T` come from?

Comment: I think he meant `protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> property)`. It is a very interesting way to do it but really inefficient since - afaik regarding expressions - it cannot be parsed and known at compile time.

Comment: @vcsjones I agree but it was a fast 'clip' and sort of out of scope - you start by calling `this.OnPropertyChanged(x => x.ExpressionText);` - which calls basically this `protected void OnPropertyChanged(Expression<Func<T, object>> property)`. That's where it gets inferred - `T` is your view model class, while object is a property type (well object all we can do)

Comment: @NtscCobalt it's a work around only - the best you can as others pointed out. It helps have the clean code, while performance might or might not be an issue (normally it isn't, it all depends). But given the question I think that's the only answer. And reduces possible errors which is the main upside to doing something like this. Again, I'm no advocating this, don't shoot the messenger :) - just stating the way to do it - which isn't new, there are couple of   questions/answers on SO with that I think.

Comment: @NSGaga, hmm well it gives me something to think about but I think `vcsjones` is probably a better answer in case someone else looks up this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the C construct, but it sounds awfully like the [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) keyword introduced in C# 6 which is

> used to obtain the simple (unqualified) string name of a variable,
>   type, or member.

If we wire it in:

```
public Double MyDouble
{
    get { return _MyDouble; }
    set
    {
        _MyDouble = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MyDouble));
    }
}
```

...and set a property value, `RaisePropertyChanged` receives a string argument of "MyDouble".