# How to get the string representation of the expression passed as an argument in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a static method that is used for checking the argument...

```
require(myStringVariable);
```

If the value does not meet some requirements, I just want do display a message.

Is it possible to display also the name of the variable (or the expression) passed as the argument? (In C++, a macro with stringize operator would do the job. Is there any equivalent or other tool to do the same in C#?)

**Update:** I am not searching anything like `nameof(myStringVariable)`. Actually, I would like to call the method also like:

```
require(bareFname + ".ext");
```

and if the expression would not pass the check, then I would to do *inside the method* something like

```
static void required(... theExpressionArgument)
{
    string value = evaluate theExpressionArgument;
    if (value.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Non empty value is required for the expression "
                          + theExpressionArgument);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `nameof(variable)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# .NET 4 stringify member name similar to #define str(s) #s in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252020/c-sharp-net-4-stringify-member-name-similar-to-define-strs-s-in-c)

Comment: I don't think he does want `nameof` because, if he used the above example, but in `requrie` the parameter is called `static void require (string myStr)` it will output `myStr` not, `myStringVariable.`

Comment: @SebastianHofmann: No. I have updated the question to explain what I need.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb: Sorry, but I do not think it is a duplicate. At least, I cannot see the similarity. It may be the case that it is not possible to do anything like this in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/672330/7571171), you could rewrite your method like this:

```
public static void RequireNotEmpty(Expression<Func<string>> lambda)
{
    // Get the passed strings value:
    string value = lambda.Compile().Invoke();

    // Run the check(s) on the value here:
    if (value.Length == 0)
    {
        // Get the name of the passed string:
        string parameterName = ((MemberExpression) lambda.Body).Member.Name;

        Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: Non empty value is required for the expression '{parameterName}'.");
    }
}
```

which can then be called like this:

```
string emptyString = "";
RequireNotEmpty(() => emptyString);
```

and writes

> ERROR: Non empty value is required for the expression 'emptyString'.

---

Note that above code assumes that you only want to check for strings. If that's not the case, you could use the signature `public static void RequireNotEmpty<T>(Expression<Func<T>> lambda)` which will then work for any type `T`.

Also I renamed the method to something I find both more readable and more meaningful.

---

## EDIT: Recommendation

After reading your comments, I figured this *might* be what you want:

```
public static class Checker
{
    private static T GetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> lambda)
    {
        return lambda.Compile().Invoke();
    }

    private static string GetParameterName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> lambda)
    {
        return ((MemberExpression) lambda.Body).Member.Name;
    }
   
    private static void OnViolation(string message)
    {
        // Throw an exception, write to a log or the console etc...
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    // Here come the "check"'s and "require"'s as specified in the guideline documents, e.g.

    public static void RequireNotEmpty(Expression<Func<string>> lambda)
    {
        if(GetValue(lambda).Length == 0)
        {
            OnViolation($"Non empty value is required for '{GetParameterName(lambda)}'.");
        }
    }

    public static void RequireNotNull<T>(Expression<Func<T>> lambda) where T : class
    {
        if(GetValue(lambda) == null)
        {
            OnViolation($"Non null value is required for '{GetParameterName(lambda)}'.");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

And now you can utilise the `Checker` class like this:

```
public string DoStuff(Foo fooObj, string bar)
{
    Checker.RequireNotNull(() => fooObj);
    Checker.RequireNotEmpty(() => bar);

    // Now that you checked the preconditions, continue with the actual logic.
    ...
}
```

Now, when you call `DoStuff` with an invalid parameter, e.g.

```
DoStuff(new Foo(), "");
```

the message

> Non empty value is required for 'bar'.

is written to the console.

Comment: I see. To summarize, the only way to get a string form of the expression into the method is to make it an not-compiled lambda expression body. Then--inside the method body--I can compile the passed representation and call it to get the value. The same way, I can still access the string representation. (There is a missing open parenthesis before the `MemberExpression`.) Is there any better way to convert `lambda.Body` to the string that was written outside? Think about writing `RequireNotEmpty(() => myEmptyVariable + "");`

Comment: @pepr *the only way* - well, there exists a way to not use costly expressions but pass a `Func<T>` instead, but it relies on IL parsing which works only for simple references (see the Reflect.cs file in https://code.google.com/archive/p/lokad-sdk/source/default/source). I'm not sure why you would want to add something to the string variable, but I would love to help you further. Can you maybe tell me more on what you want to achieve? Also, thanks for the accepted answer and thanks for mentioning the typo, I fixed it just now.

Comment: The solution is perfect for me. I really want to pass only one variable. I was just curious what is possible and what is not. Thank you. ;)

Comment: Basically, I have two functions `check()` and `require()` called at the beginning of another method to check argument values. There will be more methods like this (the outer ones) for processing a stream of data. And the passed parameter values (fed by the stream parser) should follow the Guideline document. (Type checking  at compile time is not enough.) If the `check` or `require` fails, I just want to see it (or log it somehow in future), including the place where it failed. This is the intention.

Comment: @pepr I don't know what the Guideline document states, but I edited my answer and added a design that I recommend for your `check`'s and `require`'s. Roughly following that design, you can easily create reusable parameter checks. I hope I understand correctly and this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is nice. Thank you. :) Still, it is a pitty that C# does not have C++like macros. ;)